# Error 414 The Request URL too long

Tags: php

I'm currently using CKEDITOR as plugin textarea but the problem is every time I update using the CKEDITOR it will display a bunch of code of html on the URL causing an error `"414 ERROR URL TOO LONG"` how to solve this one ?

I think there is no problem on my code and the problem is that 
the CKEDITOR is generating html codes to the URL.

I appreciate your help.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">Filter</span>

    <input id="filter" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type here...">
</div>
<table id='deleteTable' class='table'>
<thead>
  <tr>
      <td>Title</td>
      <td>Level</td>
      <td>Chapter_ID</td>
      <td>Edit</td>
      <td>Delete</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id='myTable' class='searchable'>
<?php

    include('../includes/connection/conn.php');
    //MySQL Query to read data
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * from content", $connection);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo"<tr>";
            echo"<td>{$row['title']}</td>";
            echo"<td>{$row['level']}</td>";
            echo"<td>{$row['chapter_id']}</td>";
            echo"<td><a href=\"managecontent.php?update={$row['id']}\"> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a></td>";
            echo "<td><a href=\"managecontent.php?delete={$row['id']}\"> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a></td>";
        echo"</tr>";

}
?>
</tbody>
</table>

<?php

if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
$id = $_GET['did'];
$title = $_GET['dtitle'];
$level = $_GET['dlevel'];
$chapter_id = $_GET['dchapter_id'];
$content= $_GET['dcontent'];//variable for updating content (CKEDITOR TEXTAREA)
$query = mysql_query("update content set
title='$title', level='$level',
contents='$content' where id='$id'", $connection);
}

?>

<!-- START UPDATE PART CODES -->
<?php
if (isset($_GET['update'])) {
$update = $_GET['update'];
$query1 = mysql_query("select * from content where id=$update", $connection);
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
            echo "<form class='form-horizontal' method='get'>";
                echo"<div id='updatechapter' col-lg-12'>";

                    echo"<input class='input' type='hidden' name='did' value='{$row1['id']}' />";
                    echo"<h1> Update Content: </h1>";
                    echo"<label>Title:</label>";
                    echo"<input type='text' name='dtitle' value='{$row1['title']}'  class='form-control' placeholder='eg. Basics of PHP'>";

                    echo"<label>Level:</label>";

                    echo"<select name='dlevel' class='form-control btn btn-primary'>";
                      echo"<option selected>Choose Category</option>";
                      echo"<option value='1'>Beginners</option>";
                      echo"<option value='2'>Advance</option>";
                      echo"<option value='3'>Expert</option>";
                    echo"</select>";


                   echo"<label>Chapter ID:</label>";
                   echo"<input type='text' name='dchapter_id' value='{$row1['chapter_id']}'  class='form-control' placeholder='eg. Basics of PHP' readonly>";

                    //this is the plugin 
                    echo"<label>Content:</label>";
                    echo"<textarea name='dcontent' id='Contents' rows='20'> {$row1['contents']} </textarea>";
                    echo"<script>";
                        echo"CKEDITOR.replace( 'Contents',{toolbarStartupExpanded : true} );";                     
                    echo"</script>";


                    echo"<br>";
                    echo"<button type='submit' name='submit' value='update' class='btn btn-danger form-control'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved'></span> Save Changes</button>";
                echo"</div>";

            echo "</form>";
}
}
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
$message = "Data Updated Successfully!";

echo "<script> alert('{$message}'); </script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You can just switch your request type from GET to POST.

Comment: But if i change the request type it will not display all the data included on my database.

Comment: Change everything from GET to POST. Also connections to db etc...